# Creating a neo4j sessionfactory in SDN 5.0.0

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-5

**Background**

I have a Maven, Spring data Neo4j project. It posts and gets a single object. I am trying to add sessions, but running into errors.

There are docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/#reference:session

They suggest this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackages = "org.neo4j.example.repository")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class MyConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory sessionFactory() {
        // with domain entity base package(s)
        return new SessionFactory(configuration(), "org.neo4j.example.domain");
    }

    @Bean
    public org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration configuration() {
        ConfigurationSource properties = new ClasspathConfigurationSource("ogm.properties");
        org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration configuration = new org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration.Builder(properties)
        return configuration;
    }

    @Bean
    public Neo4jTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new Neo4jTransactionManager(sessionFactory());
    }

}
```

But when I copy the second `@Bean` my eclipse marks: `new org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration.Builder(properties)` as red and suggests that I change type configuration to Builder. Then keeps suggesting changes until the 2nd `@Bean` looks like:

```
@Bean
public Builder configuration() {
    ConfigurationSource properties = new ClasspathConfigurationSource("ogm.properties");
    Builder configuration = new org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration.Builder(properties);
    return configuration;
}
```

But then the 1st `@Bean` stops working because it expects a `configuration()`.

**Question**

So, how do add a sessionfactory when the current doc's suggestion doesn't work? I have looked at many other examples, but they all use older versions with deprecated things like `Neo4jConfiguration`

**Notes**

My pom.xml has no parents and these dependencies and repositories:

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.M3</version>
    </dependency>



<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.M3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.voodoodyne.jackson.jsog</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jsog</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>



  </dependencies>



  <repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-libs-release</id>
        <name>Spring Releases</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

**UPDATE 1**

Deleting all `@Bean`s and trying this persons setup: [Why does Neo4j OGM with Spring Boot 2.0.0.M4 apparently require the embedded driver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46356002/why-does-neo4j-ogm-with-spring-boot-2-0-0-m4-apparently-require-the-embedded-dri) 
like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableNeo4jRepositories("com.myproject.repository")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class ServiceRegistryConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration configuration() {
        return new org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration.Builder(new ClasspathConfigurationSource("ogm.properties")).build();
    }
    @Bean
    public SessionFactory sessionFactory() {
        return new SessionFactory(configuration(), "com.myproject.domain");
    }

}
```

resulted in this error:

```
 ...Factory method 'configuration' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
```

my `ogm.properties` file is:

```
server.port=8585
spring.data.neo4j.uri=bolt://localhost
spring.data.neo4j.username=myuser
spring.data.neo4j.password=mypass
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your initial configuration looks good, except there's a missing **`.build()`** after the builder instantiation (it's a typo in the doc).

So the configuration init should be :

```
new org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration.Builder(properties).build();
```

About the 2nd : you cannot mix SDN style configuration and Spring Boot auto-configuration.

**Either** you use *SDN style* (as in your first code snippet) and the `ogm.properties` file looks like :

```
URI=bolt://localhost
username=myUser
password=myPassword
```

Example [here](https://github.com/neo4j-examples/neo4j-sdn-ogm-issue-report-template/tree/master/sdn-5.0)

**OR** you use *Spring Boot auto-configuration* then no need to declare the configuration, sessionFactory and transaction manager in the configuration class. Just annotate the configuration with

```
@EnableNeo4jRepositories("com.myproject.repository")
@EntityScan(basePackages = "com.myproject.domain")
```

and use the spring boot properties format :

```
spring.data.neo4j.uri=bolt://localhost
spring.data.neo4j.username=myuser
spring.data.neo4j.password=mypass
```

Example [here](https://github.com/neo4j-examples/neo4j-sdn-ogm-issue-report-template/tree/master/boot-2.0)

Regarding the `NullPointerException` : it's because the `ogm.properties` file is not found in the classpath.